# Creating typescript singleton for different Pouchdb instances

Tags: node.js, typescript, pouchdb

I have a node application that interacts with multiple databases. I've created a class which then I initiate creating the different databases (they largely have the same CRUD pattern.

Class:

```
class CRUDService {

  private section: string;
  private pouch: any;

  constructor(section: string) {
    this.section = section;
    this.pouch = new PouchDB('.' + section, pouchOptions);
  }

  public create(data: any): Promise<string> {}

  public retrieve(id: string): Promise<string> {}

  public update(id: any, data: any): Promise<string> {}

  public delete(item: any): Promise<string> {}

  public all(): Promise<string> {}

export {CRUDService};
```

DB Initiation:

```
function Users() {
  return new CRUDService('users');
}

export {Users};
```

And then I use it throughout the application like so:

```
import {Users} from 'databases';
const userService = Users();

userService.something()
```

I'm noticing that in this setup, the Users databases is being initialized multiple times. I think what I need to solve this is a Singleton. I understand what I a Singleton is but am having trouble using one in this case.

Any help or guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: you would want to keep some form of static instance of the `Users` and check if the instance is null.If so, set the instance to a new `CRUDService('user')`,  If not, return the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you necessarily need a singleton, you could simply store the database instances on static field in `CRUD Service`, using a map (also could just be an object):

```
class CRUDService {

    private static pouchDb: Map<string, PouchDB> = new Map<string, PouchDB>();

    private section: string;
    private pouch: any;

    constructor(section: string) {
        this.section = section;

        if (!CRUDService.pouchDb.has(this.section)) {
            CRUDService.pouchDb.set(section, new PouchDB('.' + section, pouchOptions));
        }

        this.pouch = CRUDService.pouchDb.get(this.section);
    }

    public create(data: any): Promise<string> {}

    public retrieve(id: string): Promise<string> {}

    public update(id: any, data: any): Promise<string> {}

    public delete(item: any): Promise<string> {}

    public all(): Promise<string> {}
}
```

Of course you could break this database instance management out into another class.

Comment: thanks for taking a look... the second line produces some errors "Error:(7, 39) TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'PouchDB' as a type."

Comment: How are you importing `PouchDB`? You could also use type `any` instead of `PouchDB`, it just won't  have type safety (or very good editor auto-complete if you're using that).

Comment: `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';` if I try `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb'` it looses those type errors but causes other issues since PouchDB. Tried to use any instead of PouchDB and although it got rid of all type errors, the app isn't running as intended. Can something be done at the Users() level or it really needs to be addressed in the parent class?

Comment: sorry meant `import {PouchDB} from 'pouchdb'` in that second code snippet above

Comment: It looks like there's ongoing issues with PouchDB and TypeScript: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6672. The last comment on this issue appears to provide a possible solution

Comment: I saw that too. actually tried the object method and it seems to be working well. `private static pouchDb = {};` and `this.pouch = CRUDService.pouchDb[this.section];` Thanks for your help!